# Is there a funny expression for "Keep it simple"?

Tags: expressions

There is an expression in my native language that goes "Don't try to give birth to a bicycle". It usually encourages someone to use a solution that has already been found, or to refrain from making some trivial process overly complicated. I'm familiar with the canonical "Don't re-invent the wheel", but I don't find it particularly funny.

Comment: A variant on FumbleFingers' reply is KISMIF: _Keep it simple, make it fun_. But that's not particularly amusing. Maybe you can tailor the Irina Dunn quip "_A woman needs a man like a fish needs a bicycle_" into something like "_Don't try to force fish to ride bicycles_".

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to make up my own (awkward) expression no one has ever heard before. Thanks for the suggestion! It is in the ballpark.

Comment: Then there's Robert Heinlein's famous quote: _"Never try to teach a pig to sing; it wastes your time and it annoys the pig."_ However, that's more applied toward avoiding the trap of trying to get people to do something that's against their nature to do, esp. when they probably can't be trained to do it effectively.

Comment: @Bill Franke: I'm not sure it makes much sense to look for an expression that is actually "amusing". Assuming we're looking for something used *in common parlance*, even the [The Funniest Joke in the World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Joke_in_the_World) would have worn flat by now. Though I must admit, even remembering the sketch about that one still makes me smile, decades later.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Except the O.P. is explicitly asking for a "funny" expression.

Comment: @J.R.: I read that as meaning he wants something intended to be somewhat light-hearted. If the requirement is that he (or anyone else) should actually find it "amusing", I'll just vote to close as Off Topic. ELU isn't a joke factory.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I like the OP's native-language expression, but I can't think of anything in common English parlance that's similar. KISMIF is platitudinous and Polonius-like.

Comment: @Bill: Well, OP presumably knows what the idioms in his own language actually mean - but I must admit I can't see much connection between *"Don't try to give birth to a bicycle"* and *"Don't try to reinvent the wheel"*. It seems to me these are rather different concepts - one's about *keeping it simple*, the other is about *leveraging existing resources*. Plus, of course, there's Kristina's *do nothing you don't absolutely **need** to do*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In both cases, something that's unnecessary is being done. I tried to find an example to show here, but it seems that this expression is far less popular than I thought.

Comment: @Fumble: "Don't try to give birth to a bicycle" seems to be about not trying to do the impossible, like forcing a fish to ride a bike or teaching a pig to sing (the Heinlein quote that J.R. suggested). KISS is, IMHO, more appropriate here (& meets the "amusing" criterion because of "stupid") than "If it ain't broke...", which is also amusing and chagrining to me because I've too often broken things that weren't broken until I tried to fix them. I agree that birthing a bicycle & reinventing the wheel aren't equivalent: the former's impossible & the latter's unnecessary.

Comment: How about *Eschew obfuscation*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd normally say [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) *("Keep it simple, stupid!")*, where you're advising someone not to [overengineer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering) a solution.

In some contexts, ["Softly, Softly, Catchee Monkey"](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Where_does_the_expression_%27softly_softly_catchy_monkey%27_come_from) may be appropriate. It's usually used to mean *Don't alarm {your quarry}*, but it wouldn't seem unreasonable to me if you said it to a colleague when you meant *We can solve this problem by doing something inconspicuous that won't require us to seek approval from the boss* (in the UK, [Don't make a song and dance about it](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/make-a-song-and-dance-about-sth).)

Comment: We call that same concept "flying under the radar" or "rather beg forgiveness than ask permission". :-)

Answer (score 2):

An expression that has similar meaning:

***If it ain't broke, don't fix it***

Comment: I'm upvoting this as the "funny" version of [leave well alone](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+well+alone), but I don't really think it has the same meaning as OP's - which I assume must mean either *don't make your solution too complicated*, *don't re-solve problems that have already been overcome*, or maybe *don't attempt the impossible*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks! It's the first thing I thought of (after the image of giving birth to a bicycle cleared from my mind).  My interpretation is that if a serviceable solution already exists, why put the effort into a new, and unproven, idea. (and KISS was already suggested!)